# <Timer> de 'react-compound-timer' pierde el scope a la hora de actualizar el estado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, react-redux

Estoy tratando de crear un componente con props que cambian según el tiempo. Al principio funciona bien pero despues de actualizar las props no se ven reflejadas en el  pero si en el consol.log, pareciera un problema de scope, pero no entiendo por que, o como solucionarlo.

```
export default class TimerDisplay extends Component {
  render() {
   console.log(this.props.step)
    return (
  <div>      
   <Timer initialTime=this.props.step}
    startImmediately={false}
    direction="backward"
    lastUnitq="ms"
    timeToUpdate={1}
   >
</Timer>
```

Comment: Creo que seria una buena idea si compartes el codigo en https://codesandbox.io/ asi es mas fácil ver lo que intentas hacer y sera mas facil que alguien te ayude

Answer (score 1):

Las props no deben actualizarse, para ello debes definir un estado, creando una variable llamada state y colocando ahí los valores que quieres referenciar en el componente.

Cuando quieras actualizar el estado usa el método setState y pasa como argumento un objeto con los mismos nombres de propiedad que tenía el objeto anterior en state.

Comment: no importa que use, pops, state sigo sin poder cambiar el valor de initalTime, ya trate muchos caminos, todo lo demas se actulaoza pero solo ese valor no :(